# STM32F4077 is not starting PLL (PLLRDY bit is not set)

Tags: stm32, infinite-loop

I try to initialize a clock system with HSE source, but the PLL is not getting ready  (PLLRDY bit is not set), during debugging I figured out an infinite loop on that condition
`while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));`
but the code is actually good, my groupmate wrote it and checked. just in case  write it below.

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"                  // Device header
    
    void MCO_Init(void);
    
    int main(void)
{
    FLASH->ACR = FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY;

    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON; //????? (8)
    while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY));

    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_Msk;
    RCC->CFGR |= 0b100 << RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_Pos; //APB2 AHB/2
    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_Msk;
    RCC->CFGR |= 0b101 << RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_Pos; //APB1 AHB/4

    RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC; //HSE —- PLL
    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Msk;
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= 8 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos; // /8
    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Msk;
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= 336 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos;// *336
    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_Msk;
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= 2 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_Pos; // /2 PLL = 168

    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));

    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_1;
    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_SW_0; // PLL —- AHB
    while(!((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS_1) && (RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_0)));


    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;                            //Enable Clock for PORTD

    GPIOD->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE15_0;                            //Outpet Mode
    GPIOD->OTYPER &=~ GPIO_OTYPER_OT15;                                 //Push-Pull
    GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED15_0;                        //Medium Speed
    
    GPIOD->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE13_0;                              //Output Mode
    GPIOD->OTYPER &=~ GPIO_OTYPER_OT13;                               //Push-Pull
    GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED13_0;                      //Medium Speed
    while (1)
    {
            GPIOD->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS15;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i ++);
            GPIOD->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR15;

            GPIOD->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS13;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i ++);
            GPIOD->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR13;

    }
}
```

Could anyone help me to figure out how to fix it?((((

Comment: Which STM32 are you using? Are you definitely meeting the operating conditions for the PLL (input frequency, VCO frequency etc)?

Comment: I'm using f407 with discovery lit. I'm actually using a code, that works on another f407's, but don't work on mine one.

Comment: A problem was solved by itself. I did nothing, just it began working one day))